# Triggering Cordova Camera Plugin w/ Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, cordova

I am trying to trigger the cordova camera plugin from inside reactjs. In previous iterations It was utilizing a simple HTML5 file input.

Upon further research I discovered that that the current webview that cordova uses for android platforms does not provide an option for camera control (thus the native cordova plugin).

I am trying to trigger the cordova camera plugin from inside reactjs after being built with:

`npm run build`

then the contents of the app's build directory are coppied to cordovas 'www' directory.

The Cordova app is relatively vanilla and camera plugin added with the command.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

Here is the config.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="^3.0.2" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.1.4" />
</widget>
```

The React Component is as follows

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Alert } from "reactstrap";
import "../../Containers/containers.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import userTools from "../../Services/userTools";

class Avatar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      avatar: "https://denisol.se/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/empty-avatar.jpg"
    };
  }
  takepicture() {
    if (!window.cordova) {
      var Camera;
      //Unless theres another way to suppress webpack
      //During Build
    }
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
      file => this.readFiles(file),
      err => console.log(err),
      {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
      }
    );
  }

  readFiles(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.addEventListener(
      "load",
      () => {
        console.log(reader.result);
        this.setState({
          avatar: reader.result
        });
      },
      false
    );
  }
  render() {
    var avatarurl;
    if (this.props.myinfo && this.props.myinfo.avatar.avatar.url) {
      avatarurl = this.props.myinfo.avatar.url;
    } else {
      avatarurl =
        "https://denisol.se/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/empty-avatar.jpg";
    }
    if (this.props.new) {
      avatarurl = this.state.avatar;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          id="avatar"
          alt="test"
          src={avatarurl}
          onClick={() => {
            if (this.props.updatable || this.props.new) {
              this.takepicture();
              //As for normal html input you would do the following
              this.refs.fileUploader.click();
            }
          }}
        />
        <input
          type="file"
          name="avatar"
          ref="fileUploader"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          accept="image/*;capture=camera"
          capture
          onChange={e => {
            if (e.target.files.length && this.props.updatable) {
              userTools.updateAvatar(e.target.files[0]);
            } else if (e.target.files.length && this.props.new) {
              this.readFiles(e.target.files[0]);
              this.props.newAvatar(e.target.files[0]);
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { myinfo: state.myinfoReducer };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Avatar);
```

when i execute the function there seems to be no response from cordova (permissions request, camera opening, ect...). Note that this component is only part of a larger react project where everything else is working more or less as expected.

Any Help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: hi, could you please provide more information? maybe it's lacking permissions, maybe it's related with calling cordova before the deviceready event. if not asking for too much, a sample project could clarify the situation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I added some more detailed content to the original question. I'm not sure the deviceready event would be an issue if your already requiring an "onClick()" event to capture the image. If still required I can create a sample project that would more effectively isolate and recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i made [this sample repo](https://github.com/sombriks/cordova-react-issue) to study the problem and it seems to be recovering the image correctly.

By doing this and reading the event handling docs, a possible cause could be the lack of bind() on handlers since this is a class component.

Please see the repo and i really rope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that I will test it out tomorrow. That "takepic" function looks wildly different from any documentation that I have looked at regarding this. It looks like it would return a data url to be used locally. Out of curiosity how would/could one go about setting the param to return a file object. Thanks again though for your support.

Comment: oh, its different but  does almost everything the cordova docs said it's possible. i just omited the options parameter so it's returning a file uri which is the default return type: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#module_camera.getPicture

Comment: Thanks Sombriks (sorry was on holiday) that works great. For the react stuff I am using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). Then Using their build script to create a static folder that is then copied over and served by cordova. Loosely following [this](https://github.com/sriramrudraraju/create-react-app-and-cordova/wiki/Creating-Structure-for-Create-react-app-and-Cordova) guide. I don't mind merging them as you did, however I'm not sure Where you loaded that /src folder in your sample repo. My src folder would look different so I'm curious how your loading it.

Comment: Hi! my approach was to create a cordova project, later a react project and then merge them piec by piece. for empty projects it's easier than sounds. i did it for cordova and vue too, it's a good reference if you want to build a similar infrastructure: https://sombriks.com.br/#/blog/0004-vuejs-into-a-cordova-project.md

Comment: it was built with browserify but create-react-app will work too. see the package.json of both projects and you will see in the scripts section the real trick.

Comment: Il give it a go merging the two together thanks for everything including the tip about the scripts.

Comment: Okay so I created a sample repo [here](https://github.com/jobobo21/cordova-react-camera-issue/tree/master) that highlights the issue that I'm having. The problem persisted after merging the two other projects together. Thanks again so much for all the support.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the camera functionality working by migrating my react project over to browserify. Not the simplest solution but will work for the time being thanks for that tip.